# How to use segue in navigation SWIFT Xcode?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I'm building a simple dictionary app. I've gotten it to display words on UItableView while user is searching or not. I'm working on assigning each individual word with its own definition but I'm facing a trouble while setting the destination for each word at words array.

Here is part of my ViewController class and its contents:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var wordSearch = [String]()
var wordArray: [String] = []
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "zo_words", withExtension: "txt")! // file URL for file "words_alpha.txt"

    do {
        let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
 }
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return wordSearch.count
        } else {
            return wordArray.count
                }
```

Here is my wordSearch function:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    wordSearch = wordArray.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased();})
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'ViewController' Error is raised in below function while building

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
        destination.word = wordArray[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
```

class DefinitionViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbDefinition:
        UILabel!
    var word: ViewController?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        lbDefinition.text = "\((word?.wordSearch)!)"
}
```

}

Comment: It would help yourself if you find out what the segue does for yourself.

Comment: im using segue to "show" the definition when a word is clicked from the UItableView.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
      static var wordSearch = [string]()
 }

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var lbDefinition:UILabel!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   lbDefinition.text = "\(ViewController.wordSearch)"
 }
}
```

Comment: changing word to a String defeats the purpose in that i can no longer call wordSearch.

Comment: i think my problem is that i dont have a seperate class for word. All I have is the class ViewController: UIViewController { } which consists of wordArray of strings, and searchWord, which is string of typed in search word by user.

Comment: Can you post both VIewControllers ? I can have a look at.
is wordSearch function inside a extension of String class?

Comment: they are both in the post. The first class is on the main ViewController. The second class is DefinitionViewController. I am trying to call the main class ViewController from DefinitionViewClass using the var word: ViewController? But there's an error on the main class ViewController prepare function saying I cant assign type string to ViewController as I did in the Definition class as previously stated,

Comment: make `wordSearch` `static`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not applicable and recommended to take an instance from the `ViewController` but you can do it so easy by using the below:
Let's say you've `word` in your `viewController`then you have to do the below:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        guard tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil  else {
            return
        }

        let selectedWord = wordArray[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]

        let destination = segue.destination as! DefinitionViewController

        destination.word = selectedWord
    }
```

DefinitionViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbDefinition:
        UILabel!
    var word: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard word != nil else {return}
        lbDefinition.text = "\((word?.wordSearch)!)"
    }
}
```

Comment: changing word to String type does not work because then I can't call wordSearch() in DefinitionViewController class.

Comment: can you add wordSearch function to be able to check it

Comment: can you add it to the post to be able to check it?

Comment: But I don't think you can take a variable or word instance from ViewController, You can create struct or class for it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0Hx7q26Hoo&ab_channel=SwiftTutorials
im following this tutorial. Im all set until video is at 23:11. thanks for the help

Comment: in video it doesn't appear the data type ? Just like i told you ProductArray is an array of products which is a struct or class so create your own one and work with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226074/discussion-between-burmesepapi-and-menaim).